# Select form field not populating with options from state in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, components

This is my select function

```
import React from "react";

const Select = ({ name, label, options, error, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <select {...rest} id={name} name={name} className="form-control">
        <option value="" />
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>
            {option.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Select;
```

This is the component state

```
state = {
    data: {
      vat: "",
      city: "",
      country: "",
      mobile_number: "",
      address: "",
      has_conference: false,
      star_rating: "",
    },
    errors: {},
    hotel_type: [],
  };
```

This function to populate data in the `hotel_type`

```
populateHotel_Types = () => {
    let hotel_type = [...this.state.hotel_type];
    hotel_type = [
      { id: "hotel", value: "hotel", name: "Hotel" },
      { id: "apartment", value: "apartment", name: "Apartment" },
      { id: "villa", value: "villa", name: "Villa" },
    ];
    this.setState({ hotel_type });
  };
```

And Finally this is the render function

```
           {this.renderSelect(
              "hotel_type",
              "Hotel Type",
              this.state.hotel_type
            )}
```

Render select function

```
renderSelect(name, label, options) {
    const { data, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <Select
        options={options}
        name={name}
        value={data[name]}
        label={label}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        error={errors[name]}
      />
    );
  }
```

Now i am struggling to get the data populated in the `renderselect` function. I am quite new to react and i am actually assuming this might be a silly question therefore kindly bear with me. What could be wrong with this code. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think in first place, you have a problem here:

```
populateHotel_Types = () => {
    let hotel_type = [...this.state.hotel_type];
    hotel_type = [
      { id: "hotel", value: "hotel", name: "Hotel" },
      { id: "apartment", value: "apartment", name: "Apartment" },
      { id: "villa", value: "villa", name: "Villa" },
    ];
    this.setState({ hotel_type });
  };
```

Here, you are filling hotel_type with your state. And below, you are redefining the array, so you will have just this 3 new objects. So should do this to have the full list:

```
 populateHotel_Types = () => {
    const hotel_type = [
       ...this.state.hotel_type,
      { id: "hotel", value: "hotel", name: "Hotel" },
      { id: "apartment", value: "apartment", name: "Apartment" },
      { id: "villa", value: "villa", name: "Villa" },
    ];
    this.setState({ hotel_type });
  };
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. The select options remain empty. When i clg i get empty array on the console

Answer (score 0):

I suspected this was a silly question and indeed it was. I was forgetting to run the function `populateHotel_Types` in the `componentDidMount` function. Therefore the state was not being updated appropriately. I am leaving this here so that any newbie like myself will get an answer to such a scenario